# Can I align text in between an image and a table?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and I'm having trouble getting a certain page to look the way I want for a project. I have an image floated on the left and a table on the right but as soon I add text in (which I would prefer in between the two) it pushes the table down the page.

CSS for the table and the image:

```
.charactertable
{
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
}

.characters.img
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: give us jsfiddle please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image is left-floated and the table has float: right, you need to put them in proper order in HTML, if you plan to add text in between.

The order should be this:

```css
.charactertable {
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
    border: 2px #DDD solid;
}
.characters.img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="" class="characters img">

<table class="charactertable">
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas cumque voluptatum est esse ea. Quis nulla cumque nihil vitae ipsa excepturi veniam ut perspiciatis quibusdam minima ipsam reprehenderit. Deserunt reiciendis.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the order I had wrong in html code just as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some code?
Anyway
Try adding your text inside a div and centering the div.
for example:

```
<div id="center">This will be centered between something</div>

CSS
#center{
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
```